# Loop through "dist" matrix

Tags: r

Let's first create `dist` object:

```
data(iris)
X <- iris[1:10, -5]
D <- dist(X)
```

I wonder how to iterate through rows / columns of `dist` object (e.g., compute sum of the rows)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert the `dist` matrix to `matrix` by wrapping with `as.matrix`.  This will give a symmetric matrix will diagonals as 0.  As we need only either the lower or upper triangular values, we can assign one of them to '0' and do the `rowSums`

```
m1 <- as.matrix(D)
m1[upper.tri(m1, diag=TRUE)] <- 0
rowSums(m1)
colSums(m1)
```

Or we multiply (`*`) 'm1' with the logical index from the numeric `row` and `col` index of the matrix 'm1'.  The `TRUE/FALSE` values from the logical matrix will be transformed to `1/0` and when we multiply, values in 'm1' that correspond to '0' values will become 0 and others stay the same.

```
rowSums(m1*(row(m1)>col(m1)))
```